# Implement a select inside swiper:

Tags: swiper.js

I want to implement a select element which is from the Headlessui library inside the swiper slider, but the behavior it has is not as expected, when displaying the select options it does not just show its options, only part is shown , I have checked the styles of the containers and everything turns out to be in its place...
Am I applying to my Vue component something wrong? Is it possible that some swiper method makes the Select component difficult? outside of swiper the Select component works correctly...

Greetings

```
<template>
    <div class="mt-4">
        <swiper
            :modules="modules"
            :slides-per-view="1"
            :centered-slides="true"
            :space-between="0"
            navigation
            :keyboard="true"

            @swiper="onSwiper"
            @slideChange="onSlideChange">

            <swiper-slide>
                <div class="text-white">
                    <p class="font-georgiabolditalic text-2xl">Descubre tu grado de saturación:</p>
                    <p class="font-travelbold text-4xl">
                        <span class="font-georgiaitalic text-custom_green">1.</span>
                        ¿Que tema te sobrepasa?
                    </p>
                    <p class="font-georgiaitalic text-4xl">ENORMEMENTE</p>
                    <p class="font-travelbold text-4xl">que lo escuchas y dices,</p>
                    <p class="font-georgiaitalic text-custom_green text-3xl">"mira, estoy hasta el/la/los/ las..."?</p>
                    <Select />
                </div>
            </swiper-slide>

            <swiper-slide>
                ...
            </swiper-slide>

            <swiper-slide>
                ...
            </swiper-slide>

            <swiper-slide>
               ...
            </swiper-slide>
        </swiper>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    // import Swiper core and required modules
    import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
    import Select from '../Components/Select.vue';
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

    // Import Swiper styles
    import 'swiper/css'
    import 'swiper/css/navigation'


    export default{
        name: 'Questionnaire',

        components: {
            Select,
            Swiper,
            SwiperSlide,
        },

        setup() {
            let swiper = null;

            const onSwiper = (instance) => {
                swiper = instance;
            };

            const onSlideChange = () => {
                console.log('slide change');
            };
            
            const swiperModules = [Pagination, Navigation]

            return {
                onSwiper,
                onSlideChange,
                modules: [Navigation, Pagination]
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

I don't have the expected behavior of the Select component

Comment: Your Q is not clear. Try to add minimal working example (snippet) + some screenshots of the problem